# Input file required when text field is fillen

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input, required

I am trying to create a form where for each entry that is not empty, there must be an attachment. So, when the name field is filled, the associated input file should turn into required using JQuery. I used the following code, but the form gets submitted either way.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //option A
                $("#form").submit(function(e){
                    if($("#name").val() != ""){ 
                        $("#file").prop('required',true);
                    } 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" action="action.php">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Attachment</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></th>
                    <th><input type="text" name="id" id="id"></th>
                    <th><input type="file" name="file" id="file" ></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="text" name="name1" id="name1"></th>
                    <th><input type="text" name="id1" id="id1"></th>
                    <th><input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your function is validating the name field only on submission which is too late. You should validate using another event, like `keyup` or `changed`.

Comment: @dommmm I used change() instead and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is validating the name field only on submission which is too late, as the form will have initiated the submission action before running your validation.

You should instead validate using another event, like `keyup` or `changed`.

Answer (score 0):

It will be submitted right away without validating because of your `action="action.php"`. In order for you to manipulate your DOM inside the `.submit()` function, you have to remove the `action` attribute in your form tag.